# Escaping ampersand for Google Analytics UTM on Tumblr

Tags: google-analytics, tumblr

I'm trying to track referrals to my site from links within Tumblr posts on the mobile app. According to google, the UTM code should look something like the following:

`mysite.com/?utm_source=tumblr&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=tumblr`

However, when the user clicks this link on Tumblr, it opens the browser with this URL instead:

`mysite.com/?utm_source=tumblr&amp;utm_medium=referralr&amp;utm_campaign=tumblr`

The second link isn't showing Tumblr as the source in google analytics. For some reason, this only happens on the Tumblr mobile app--the ampersand remains unescaped on my desktop browser, and it worked on other mobile apps like my  Instagram bio.

My question is, what might be causing Tumblr to treat this link differently, and is there a reason the UTM code only works with a plain `&` and not with `&amp;`?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30177372/1591669).

Comment: It depends how your links get there to Tumblr. If you write them in manually, Tumblr editor might intervene. If it goes there by some application which uses Tumblr API - then it is error in use of API on application level.